# error while referencing sqlite-net-pcl package in Xamarin forms Android project

Tags: forms, xamarin, build, sqlite-net-pcl

I am getting the following error when i attempt to reference the `sqlite-net-pcl` package in the Android project of `Xamarin` forms project. I get this error when building in release mode but debug mode seems to be fine. 
I am using

sqlite-net-pcl 1.4.118

Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.282

Xamarin.Android.Support.* 25.4.0.2

```
Error Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SQLite-net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'SQLite-net.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver) CouchPortfolioApp.Android
```

Answer (score 2):

You should reference sqlite-net-pcl in your target platform project as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `sqlite-net-pcl` and .NET Standard 2.0 when I was  building in debug mode. I changed the linker and cleaned and rebuilt the solution (I even deleted the bin and obj folder).

In the properties of the project -> android options -> linking -> "SDK assembly Only"

In my case in release worked with "None"

Android Options:

[image]